# how to access error information in Step Function from previous Function in Catch state

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I am wondering how to access the cause of my custom exception raised inside my lambda function. I need to access it at the end of my Step Functions workflow, as shown below.

The diagram below is an example of a failed execution. The error (`error-info` object, with its' own `Error` and `Cause` sections) is found in the output of `ParseTextractOutput`, but I am wondering how to access it in `OutputNotFound` as shown below.

#### Step Functions Diagram

[image]

#### Output

The output of `ParseTextractOutput` is

```
{
  "event"...
  "error-info": {
    "Error": "OutputNotFoundException",
    "Cause": "{\"errorMessage\": \"Contents of Textracted file: {...}}"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to access this data somehow in these fields (of the Step Functions definition):

```
...
  "States": {
    "OutputNotFound": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "<useful stuff here, like $.error-info.Error or something>",
      "Cause": "<useful stuff here, like $.error-info.Cause or something>"
    },
...
    "ParseTextractOutput": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "functionARN",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": ["OutputNotFoundException"],
          "ResultPath": "$.error-info",
          "Next": "OutputNotFound"
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
```

#### Python Code

Here's the relevant code for the Function `ParseTextractOutput`.

```
class OutputNotFoundException(Exception):
  pass

...

try:
  blocks = data['Blocks']
except KeyError as e:
  raise OutputNotFoundException('Contents of Textracted file: {}'.format(data))
```

Comment: You cannot actually. Fail state only takes the `Type` and `Comments` field. As you need `InputPath` to access the variables from the previous state. You can do a workaround by creating a Choice state after ParseTextractOutput based on the result you can either go to Fail state or Succeed state.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment (with the current version of https://states-language.net/spec.html) `Fail.Error` and `Fail.Cause` cannot be dynamic. The input that is passed to `Fail` state is ignored and fix strings are used for error and cause.

We can view `Fail` as a point in the execution to announce a fix message, indicate end of execution with an error and exit.

This means any processing has to be done before these announcement points. As @frosty mentioned in the comments a `Choice` state can be useful.

#### Alternative 1: using Choice

Here is an example:

[image: State machine with choice before fail states]

Let's say I have this Python code in my Lambda function:

```
class OutputNotFoundException(Exception):
  pass



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    raise OutputNotFoundException('Error message A')
```

When function returns, the output will be a JSON like this:

```
{
  "Error": "OutputNotFoundException",
  "Cause": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Error message A\",\"errorType\":\"OutputNotFoundException\",\"stackTrace\":[\"...\\n\"]}"
}
```

Notice how "Cause" is another JSON which is string encoded. We can convert `OutputNotFound` to `Pass` and use  intrinsic function `StringToJson()` to convert the encoded string to normal JSON for easier processing later:

```
    "OutputNotFound": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "details.$": "States.StringToJson($.Cause)"
      },
      "Next": "Error message?"
    },
```

Now we have an output like this:

```
{
  "details": {
    "errorMessage": "Error message A",
    "errorType": "OutputNotFoundException",
    "stackTrace": ["...\n"]
  }
}
```

Next state will be a `Choice` which looks into `$.details.errorMessage` to decide a proper Fail state:

```
    "Error message?": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.details.errorMessage",
          "StringEquals": "Error message A",
          "Next": "Error A"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.details.errorMessage",
          "StringEquals": "Error message B",
          "Next": "Error B"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "Unknown Error"
    },
```

Each choice is now pointing to a normal `Fail` state to announce a fix string:

```
    "Error A": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Error": "OutputNotFoundException",
      "Cause": "OutputNotFoundException of type A happened"
    },
```

#### Alternative 2: End with Pass

If your intention is to have the exact error message as output of your execution for later logging/processing one way can be leaving at the `Pass` state:

```
    "OutputNotFound": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "details.$": "States.StringToJson($.Cause)",
        "isError": true
      },
      "End": true
    }
```

The downside of this solution is, of course, the execution ends with a successful status and we need to process output to discover there was an error (hence the extra `isError` field above)

Answer (score 1):

Including a section of the workflow as one single branch of a [Parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html) state definition might be useful to define one exception scope, and take a new path with the exception details, like explained in this [post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/aws-step-function-tricks-part-2-328fa3bc9e50):

```
{
  "Comment": "Better error handling",
  "StartAt": "ErrorHandler",
  "States": {
    "ErrorHandler": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Hello",
          "States": {
            "Hello": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Result": "Hello",
              "Next": "World"
            },
            "World": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Result": "World",
              "Next": "Foo"
            },
            "Foo": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Result": "World",
              "Next": "Bar"
            },
            "Bar": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Result": "World",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "ResultPath": "$.error",
          "Next": "Send Failure Message"
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Job Succeeded"
    },
    "Job Succeeded": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    },
    "Send Failure Message": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "Fail Workflow"
    },
    "Fail Workflow": {
      "Type": "Fail"
    }
  }
}
```